# How do I merge shapes in different layers to one big area?

Tags: qgis, layers, merge

How do I merge shapes in different layers to one big area, I already tried "Vector > Data Management Tools > Merge Vector Layers" but that only puts the attributes of the layers in one layer. I want one big shape from the overlaping shapes so that I can see the total area size.
So really merge the layers together, maybe the path described above has already achieved my goal and I just don't see the overall size that I want, because in the attributes its still shows me the individual area sizes but not the total...

[image]

These are the single areas, for better understanding, what I mean.

Comment: You might try a dissolve after you've done the merge, then recalculate your area fields.